# JQuery POST not working with error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I try to post using JQuery, I get this error:
`jquery.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:8000/post,json 501 (Unsupported method ('POST'))`

Here's my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "./post,json",
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data.msg);
                }, data: {
                    name: "chris",
                    grade: 11
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps type is deprecated? method: "POST", _type (default: 'GET')
Type: String
An alias for method. You should use type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0._

Comment: Also, should the URL be `./post.json` instead of `./post,json`?

Comment: In java script object attribute must equal with server side object attributes. in your case maybe some of your js attribute are not identical server side obj attributes.

Comment: Does "./post.json" allow post? Perhaps only GET is set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's problem with your URL? `"./post,json"` it looks strange. Also you can't use coma in url, or you must quote it.

---

Also you can try to change data

```
data: JSON.stringify({
    name: "chris",
    grade: 11
})
```

Comment: Rookie mistake on my part there haha. I changed it to "./post.json" and I'm still getting the same error.